# Identity 2.1 - UserId not found but was working before

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

This code worked before numerous times but after adding in a couple new properties for a user in Identity 2.1 it has ceased to work suddenly. I am getting a UserId not found error, despite there being a value visible in the debugger for UserId. Anyone have an idea on why this has suddenly happened? It's very frustrating to see the least.

Here's code:
(Controller)

```
 // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        model.BackgroundOnFile = false;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userDetails = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Title = model.Title, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, LEAID = model.LEAID, SchoolID = model.SchoolID, Address1 = model.Address1, Address2 = model.Address2, City = model.City, State = model.State, PostCode = model.PostCode, BackgroundOnFile = model.BackgroundOnFile, BoardStart = model.BoardStart, BoardEnd = model.BoardEnd, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(userDetails, model.Password);


            //Assign Role
            UserManager.AddToRole(userDetails.Id, "User");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(userDetails, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

And the Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    //Extra items required to register
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int LEAID { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    //Post Code is a string to accomodate future possible Canadian style post codes
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public bool BackgroundOnFile { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BoardStart { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BoardEnd { get; set; }
    public string NominatedBy { get; set; }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
UserId not found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.

Source Error: 


Line 168:                
Line 169:                //Assign Role
Line 170:                UserManager.AddToRole(userDetails.Id, "User");
Line 171:
Line 172:                if (result.Succeeded)

Source File: h:\app\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 170 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<AddToRoleAsync>d__83.MoveNext() +871
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +409
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.AddToRole(UserManager`2 manager, TKey userId, String role) +260
   UCAP.Controllers.<Register>d__7.MoveNext() in h:\Laptop Transfer\Training Code\1\CSMapAlpha3\CSMapAlpha3\Controllers\AccountController.cs:170
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651688
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: `UserId` may have a value in the debugger but the `UserId` isn't found in the database. Have you verified that it's present in the DB?

Comment: It's "Id" in the database column. Seems to be correct afaik.

Comment: Try adding `UserManager.UpdateAsync()'` or getting the UserId by user name from the UserManager after you create the user.

Comment: @Dreamcasting I am getting the same error. how did u resolved it please suggest me waiting for ur reply

Answer (score 6):

Having the same error right now!
The only relevant recent action I've made is the update of packages 
through NuGet:

- EntityFramework 6.1.1 to 6.1.3
- Microsoft ASP.NET IdentityCore 2.1.0to 2.2.1
- Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 2.1.0 to 2.2.1
- Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Owin 2.1.0 to 2.2.1

Still investigating anyway...

**UPDATE**

In my case I was trying to generate the confirmation token before saving the user. I learned that `UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID)` generates the token upon a saved ID, not the one you have in memory.

Hope this helps, somehow.

Comment: I was trying to set a password before creating the user and this causes the same error. Call `CreateUser(User)` first and then do your operations with the email confirmation token or password codes etc.

Answer (score 4):

This exception is not generated by `Application User` class, there is no property named `UserID` in this class. (its `Id` not `UserId`)

So there are two Tables in `Identity` database contains column with `UserID`

1. `IdentityRole`
2. `IdentityUserRole`

Therefore exception is being raised during insert in these tables, there is nothing wrong with `ApplicationUser.Id`. Make sure that role with name "User" exists. also check for name case i.e. `"User"/"user"`

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you struggle to get identity framework working without fully appreciating all the ins and outs, this may help.  I was using this line to get a reference to the user:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = ...
```

This creates a new user.  What I should have done is use this line:

```
var user = UserManager.FindByEmail( ...
```

You can then reset the password like this:

```
string code = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
var result = UserManager.ResetPassword(user.Id, code, model.Password);
```

Note that this has no error-checking.